# C array to store the pointers of malloc'd arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

I'd like to store the pointers of two arrays (`*a` and `*b`) created by `malloc` in a function.

For example, if `&a[0]=0x0061FEC8` and `&b[0]=0x007700FE`, then the array to store these two pointers should be `c[0]=0x0061FEC8` and `c[1]=0x007700FE`

```
void storePointers(int **ptrArray){
    // create two arrays a and b by malloc
    int *a = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));  // a stores 5 integers
    int *b = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int)); // b stores 10 integers

    // create an array to store the pointers of a and b
    *ptrArray = (int **)malloc(2*sizeof(int*));
    (*ptrArray)[0] = a;
    (*ptrArray)[1] = b;
}

int main(){
    int *mArray = NULL;
    
    storePointers(&mArray);

    // these two lines should print 0x0061FEC8 and 0x007700FE
    printf("mArray[0]: %p\n", mArray[0]);
    printf("mArray[1]: %p\n", mArray[1]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This program actually worked. But the compiler displayed a warning message:

```
warning: assignment to 'int' from 'int *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     (*ptrArray)[0] = a;
warning: assignment to 'int' from 'int *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     (*ptrArray)[1] = b;
```

I assume `int` is common so the compiler fixed the problem by itself so that my program ran properly?  I have another similar program, but it uses `struct`. So instead of a warning, I get an error of

```
Error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'myStruct' from type 'myStruct *'
```

I would like to know the root cause and solution to get rid of the warning and ultimately the error in my struct program.

Comment: you have one less level of indirection than you need in several places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an array is `int *` then an array of arrays is `int **` and if you want to *return* an array of arrays as an out parameter, then you need a pointer to that -- `int ***`. So you need to change the type of `mArray` as well as the `ptrArray` parameter:

```
void storePointers(int ***ptrArray){
    // create two arrays a and b by malloc
    int *a = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));  // a stores 5 integers
    int *b = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int)); // b stores 10 integers

    // create an array to store the pointers of a and b
    *ptrArray = (int **)malloc(2*sizeof(int*));
    (*ptrArray)[0] = a;
    (*ptrArray)[1] = b;
}

int main(){
    int **mArray = NULL;
    
    storePointers(&mArray);

    // these two lines should print 0x0061FEC8 and 0x007700FE
    printf("mArray[0]: %p\n", mArray[0]);
    printf("mArray[1]: %p\n", mArray[1]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

That should then work if you change the type from `int` to something else.

Comment: another option is to use the return value of the funtion for returning a value